# Is there any way to change notification settings of a particular calendar in Windows 10 and Windows 10 Mobile?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook, calendar, windows-10-calendar-app

We can do it in [options](https://www.calendar.live.com/calendar/options.aspx) on live.com. But these settings don't work in desktop and mobile applications. We can turn off all calendar notifications, but this is not what I want.

[image: Calendar Options]